# cannot flush cache by code

Tags: cache

I want to flush the cache by code and I tried these in my test folder:

```
<?php
include '/var/www/myfolder/mage_classes.php';
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
```

or

```
Mage::app()->getCache()->clean();
```

none of them cleared the cache I also used

```
try {
    $cacheTypes = Mage::app()->useCache();
    foreach ($cacheTypes as $type => $option) {
        Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
}
```

also in my back end admin all cache options are enabled

and again no result when I run this code no error willl be shown and it seems that it will run but with no effect

Comment: What is mage_classes.php? You could try including /var/www/myfolder/app/Mage.php?  Anything in your error logs? enable error reporting in your script to double check.

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem but let me check because it knows every thing i write there if it wasn't it would show me error for example if I change the flush function to flu it will tell function not exists so it is not a problem

Comment: yes I checked as I guessed it wasn't a problem because in mage_classes I had already the mage.php

Comment: my errors are enabled

Comment: How do you know the cache is not cleared? Maybe the cleanType() method only invalidates the cache?

Answer (score 1):

You should really use **Magerun**. It's a very powerful tool that allows you to run a lot of basic Magento commands by command line. Very useful especially when you cannot access your backend.

More information: http://magerun.net/

Answer (score 0):

While it is a cron'd job to clear only invalidated caches, it is working code

```
<?php

/************************
 * Find invalidated cache types and refresh
 *
 * Set Cron Time for refresh in config.xml
 *
 */

class Chief_Rcache_Model_Observer {
    public function refreshCache() {
        try {
            $types = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->getInvalidatedTypes();
            foreach($types as $type) {
                Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type->getId());
            }
            Mage::log('Invalid Cache Types Refreshed');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }
}
```

Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Chief_Rcache>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Chief_Rcache>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <refresh_cache>
                <class>Chief_Rcache_Model</class>
            </refresh_cache>
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <refresh_cache>
                <!-- Min Hour Day Month DoW -->
                <schedule><cron_expr>5 */3 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>refresh_cache/observer::refreshCache</model></run>
            </refresh_cache>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Module enable file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Chief_Rcache>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Chief_Rcache>
    </modules>
</config>
```